# No tab completion for IPython in Emacs textmode

Tags: emacs, ipython, tab-completion, linux-mint

When I run IPython inside emacs in textmode (i.e. inside a terminal), I don't get any tab completion. Rather than given tab completion it jumps four spaces.

When I run emacs in normal GUI mode there is fine tab completion.

Is there a way to fix that for text mode?

I'm using Linux Mint 15, Emacs 24.3 and IPython 1.1.0

Comment: Are you getting proper python syntax highlighting in the terminal? If not, emacs may be failing to detect this is a python file.  If systax highlighting is correct, what is the output of C-h k TAB (basically, what the key is bound to)

Comment: Also, look in the *Messages* buffer for any error o warning you are not getting in GUI mode

Comment: thanks for the replies.

I did the C-h k TAB. In text mode I got:
    `TAB runs the command indent-for-tab-command, which is an interactive`
and in GUI mode i got:
    `<tab> runs the command python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `python.el'.`

I guess that is the reason for the different behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure you run the same Emacs in the GUI and in the terminal cases?  Maybe your $PATH setting is not the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(eval-after-load "python"
  '(define-key inferior-python-mode-map "\t" 'python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent)
```

If this works for you, you may have a misconfiguration problem that is preventing python mode to load correctly in your setup.

Comment: that does work. But it returns an error on startup: `Symbol's value as variable is void: python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent`

Comment: @dYz IMO define needs a quote: '(define-key, so it's not evaluated when reading. BTW current python.el does set TAB this way, maybe just upgrade.

Comment: Fixed as per @AndreasRöhler comment

Comment: Thanks!, that helped. It seems that I have the python.el from Emacs 24.2 and not the 24.3.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same problem and after some search I found that this problem is caused by the difference between `<tab>` and `TAB`. The Emacs wiki has a page describes the difference: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabKey .

In my python.el, the `python-shell-completion-complete-or-indent` is bind to `<tab>` which works fine for GUI but not for CLI. Change the binding to `TAB` will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start IPython not from pure shell, but from a python-mode.

I.e. <kbd>M-x run-python RET</kbd> with shipped python.el, having customized `python-shell-interpreter` accordingly.

Resp. <kbd>M-x IPython RET</kbd> with python-mode.el

Comment: That is how I start IPython in Emacs. I'm using the python.el that comes with Emacs.

Comment: @dYz Okay, seeing the key just isn't set by default they way you need it.